# Magento2 Website Title

Tags: magento2, meta-title

I am unable to change the Website title name.

Can any one help me to change website name on browser tab in magento2.

Comment: home page title or entire pages?

Comment: you mean page title?

Comment: no change the website Title

Answer (score 2):

In admin panel, Go to

> Content -> Element -> Pages

then **edit home page title** from there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Store -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> HTML Head -> Default Title`

Comment: this is for magento1 but not for magento2

Answer (score 0):

You can change title From Admin below Path : 
Configuration->Pick Theme->edit->HTML Head_>title
You can edit title from here.
Remove Cache and refresh it